# I want php date formate in yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss:ss.sssz. How to write code for this?

Tags: php

Please help me to find the current date in the following formate yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss:ss.sssz

Comment: At least show some effort, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+yyyy-mm-dd has 3537 results to miss before this question may be asked

Comment: I have tried like this $timestamp = gmdate(DATE_ATOM);  and also this echo  date('Y-m-dTH:i:s.uZ'); but not getting the right answer. I want the ans in perfect formate like this 2014-01-20T13:38:40.405Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $t = microtime(true);
    $micro = sprintf("%03d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000);
    $utc = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.', $t).$micro.'Z';
    echo $utc;
?>
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/qk9CIE)**

Comment: by using your code I am getting like this 2014-09-15T05:33:25+00:00 But I want in the following formate where millisecod should be in 3 digit appended with z 2012-01-20T13:38:40.405Z

Comment: @NitinJain I have edited the code. Now check the DEMO